# In how many region in $K_n$'s "interior"

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $K_n$ the complete graph on $n$ vertices. I was wondering whether there was a closed formula or recursion in $n$ for $r_n :=$ region in the "interior" of $K_n$. For example the first terms are $r_2 = 0, r_3 = 1, r_4 = 4, r_5 = 11,r_6 = 24$ and so on.

I don't see immediately a formula, but in the case of $n$ even one could consider counting only the region inside a pair of adjacent vertices and multiply that number by $n$. The case of $n$ odd I don't any repeting pattern or viable simmetry.

Is it a well known and studied problem? Is it possible to solve it? Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I right that, basically, you are asking a *geometry* question: *in how many parts do the diagonals of a **regular** $n$-gon divide its interior*? (E.g. $K_4$ can be "a square with its diagonals" or "a regular triangle with its centre connected to all three vertices" and it seems you are interested in the former but not the latter!) Also, check out https://oeis.org/A007678

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes Indeed, thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a well studied problem.

In general when working with an integer sequence, it's helpful to search it in the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://OEIS.org). Frequently the OEIS will have information about your sequence, other related sequences, generating functions, closed forms, papers that prove facts about the sequence, etc.

In your case, we can [search for 0,1,4,11,24](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C4%2C11%2C24&language=english&go=Search), and we find the top result is

> [A007678](https://oeis.org/A007678): Number of regions in regular n-gon with all diagonals drawn.

This is clearly what you're looking for, and under "formula" there's a reference to an explicit formula (due to Poonen-Rubenstein) we can find in [A006533](https://oeis.org/A006533). Since our sequence of interest is $n$ less than this sequence, we're almost there. Then we follow a link to the paper [*The Number of Intersection Points Made by the Diagonals of a Regular Polygon*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9508209.pdf) and we see there is a closed formula for A006533. You'll forgive me for using a screenshot instead of typesetting it by hand (even though this will make it unsearchable):

[image]

Here $\delta_m(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n \equiv 0 \pmod m \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$

Then, using the relationship between A006533 and our sequence of interest A007678, we see that the closed form is $R(n) - n$ where $R$ is as above.

---

I hope this helps ^_^